# Issues while deploying a whatsapp bot on vercel

Tags: node.js, deployment, puppeteer, vercel

I have created a `whatsapp bot` which uses `openai`, `whatsapp-web.js` and `nodejs`.

While `deploying` it on `vercel`, I am facing following issues:

```
Error: Failed to launch the browser process!
[0212/144729.058867:ERROR:zygote_host_impl_linux.cc(90)] Running as root without --no-sandbox is not supported.
```

These are the `output` that I am getting on `deployment`:

```
Running build in Washington, D.C., USA (East) – iad1
Cloning github.com/hritik2002/GitaGpt-Bot (Branch: main, Commit: 17356f1)
Previous build cache not available
Cloning completed: 401.653ms
Running "vercel build"
Vercel CLI 28.15.3
Running "install" command: `npm install`...
npm WARN deprecated puppeteer@13.7.0: < 18.1.0 is no longer supported
added 121 packages, and audited 122 packages in 6s
10 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details
found 0 vulnerabilities
/vercel/path0/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/BrowserRunner.js:241
            reject(new Error([
                   ^
Error: Failed to launch the browser process!
[0212/144729.058867:ERROR:zygote_host_impl_linux.cc(90)] Running as root without --no-sandbox is not supported. See https://crbug.com/638180.
TROUBLESHOOTING: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/troubleshooting.md
    at onClose (/vercel/path0/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/BrowserRunner.js:241:20)
    at Interface.<anonymous> (/vercel/path0/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/BrowserRunner.js:231:68)
    at Interface.emit (node:events:525:35)
    at Interface.close (node:internal/readline/interface:536:10)
    at Socket.onend (node:internal/readline/interface:262:10)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:525:35)
    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1359:12)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
Node.js v18.12.1
Error: Command "node app.js" exited with 1
```

My `package.json` file:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.26.1",
    "qrcode-terminal": "^0.12.0",
    "whatsapp-web.js": "^1.18.0"
  }
}
```

My `app.js` code:

```
const qrcode = require("qrcode-terminal");
const { Client, LocalAuth, MessageMedia } = require("whatsapp-web.js");
const axios = require("axios");


async function QueryMessage(message) {
  // performs certain task:
}

const client = new Client({
  authStrategy: new LocalAuth(),
});

client.initialize();

client.on("qr", (qr) => {
  qrcode.generate(qr, { small: true });
});

client.on("authenticated", () => {
  console.log("AUTHENTICATED");
});

client.on("ready", () => {
  console.log("Client is ready!");
});

const sendMessage = async (chat, message) => {
  await chat.sendMessage(await QueryMessage(message));
};

//Replying Messages with image from url
client.on("message", async (message) => {
  const chat = await message.getChat();

  if (!chat.isGroup) {
    sendMessage(chat, message.body);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't use Puppeteer with Vercel, Puppeteer is a browser running in the background.

Answer (score 0):

I hade the same isssue in node.js
solved it by adding --no-sandbox argument while creating client,

```
const client = new Client({
    authStrategy: new LocalAuth(),
    puppeteer: { 
        args: [
            '--no-sandbox'
        ]
    }
})
```